# Simple way of extracting hair pixels from an image of a human face

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, image-manipulation, face-detection

Disclaimer: I am **not** looking for a robust method that works under all conditions and/or requiring complex analysis of the image (e.g., http://vis-www.cs.umass.edu/lfw/part_labels/). Therefore please do not link me to one of the many papers on hair segmentation that exist. I am looking for something fast and simple (not perfectly robust).

That being said, my goal is to extract the area containing the hair in an image of a human face. If I am able to get at least some tiny set of pixels that I am **sure** are hair pixels, then I can use one of several algorithms to find the rest (e.g., a "photoshop magic wand" type algorithm).

An example (left side is the original face, right side is the gradient magnitude):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hR78a.jpg

Here's the information I have access to regarding any image of a human face: all locations of important features (e.g., nose, eyes, mouth and chin). One dumb/simple way of finding hair pixels could be to perform edge detection, and work up from the nose until I find two "horizontal edges" which we assume are the lower and upper boundaries of the hair, then take a sample from in-between.

Any ideas on other simple methods to try?

Comment: are you interested in facial hair as well?

Comment: only the hair on the top of the head

Comment: Have you seen [this paper](http://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/docs/00/32/27/19/PDF/Publication_ICIP_Final.pdf)? It seems similar to your "rough and ready" requirement.

Comment: I won't be going down that route, but thanks for the paper suggestion (the frequential mask/color mask looks like a straightforward approach)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using image processing techniques (edge detection) you could use simple maths. You say you know where the nose, eyes, mouth and chin are. From the distance between these body parts you can certainly determine the distance to look up from the eyes to find hair. I'm not sure which distance ratio you can use, but the hair are certainly not 10x farther than the distance between eyes and chin.
Obviously this technique is not bald-proof.

Comment: Good idea on a simple way of estimating where the hair might be. Thanks!